# Doing just one query search, saving it to an array and then search only the array instead of doing multiple sql queries

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

i have this

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
def index
    @textos = Texto.all
    @texto_historia         = Texto.where(:title => "História").first.contents
    @texto_capas_para_sofa  = Texto.where(:title => "Capas para Sofá").first.contents
    @texto_cortinas         = Texto.where(:title => "Cortinas").first.contents
    @texto_almofadas        = Texto.where(:title => "Almofadas").first.contents
end
```

The SQL output is:

```
  ←[1m←[36mTexto Load (2.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mSELECT "textos".* FROM "textos"←[0m
  ←[1m←[35mTexto Load (1.0ms)←[0m  SELECT "textos".* FROM "textos" WHERE ("textos"."title" = 'Hist├│ria') LIMIT 1
  ←[1m←[36mTexto Load (0.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mSELECT "textos".* FROM "textos" WHERE ("textos"."title" = 'Capas para Sof├í') LIMIT 1←[0m
  ←[1m←[35mTexto Load (1.0ms)←[0m  SELECT "textos".* FROM "textos" WHERE ("textos"."title" = 'Cortinas') LIMIT 1
  ←[1m←[36mTexto Load (1.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mSELECT "textos".* FROM "textos" WHERE ("textos"."title" = 'Almofadas') LIMIT 1←[0m
  ←[1m←[35mTexto Load (0.0ms)←[0m  SELECT "textos".* FROM "textos" WHERE ("textos"."title" = 'Informa├º├╡es de Contato') LIMIT 1
```

What i want is to do just one query for all "textos" model and then search inside an array or anything like that to get the specific variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to get the array of all ActiveRecord objects and convert it into a hash storing the data you need.

```
@textos = Texto.all.inject({}) {|h, obj| h[obj.title] = obj.contents; h }
```

Then you will be able to access your contents with `@textos["title"]`.

Comment: Many thanks. This answer teached me a really cool method and improved the elegancy of my code. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you want the [`find` or `find_all`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-find) option:

```
@texto_historia = @texto.find { |a| a.title = "História"}
```

Comment: Thanks. This was exactly what i was looking for. The answer below reduced the needed lines of code even more. So that's why i choosed it as the correct answer. But your answer was really useful too. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @pedrozath not at all... glad that you found the answer